# How to optimize all my apps in "Battery Optimization"?

Tags: android, optimization, xiaomi

I have xiaomi mi max 32gb -Multirom 8.4.26-

I am not a developer. I make all my apps *"battery optimized"* except these apps: (Greenify+amplify+powernap+Launcher+Appops+Magisk+ Xposed).

[image: Battery optmization]

But after rebooting my mobile, apps returns non-optimized. So I need to make all my apps optimized after every reboot. This task is tiring and wastes my time.

**My Question:** Can you help me batch optimize all apps after every reboot, please? By using *tasker* or *adb* command or mod or anything
Please help me

Comment: Hi, I think your question is out of topic for stackoverflow which is mainly about programming. You should try moving your question to another place, such as android.stackexchange.com

Comment: But before moving the thread to another place:  Is there a solution to my questions using I can apply using terminal in android?